# How to activate a dialogue box on suspend?

Tags: unity, 14.04, shutdown, suspend

I am using 14.04 with unity. Quite regularly it happens to me that I want to shutdown the computer, but in the right corner menu I accidently hit `Suspend` in stead of `Shutdown`.

Is it possible to add a dialogue box on the suspend menu? So that I don't always have to come back from suspend to finally shutdown afterwards.

Or is it possible to make the shutdown button like 3 times bigger than the suspend button?

Comment: If this is a laptop, then that dialogue box would block suspend when you close the lid. Do you have a desktop, or are you willing to deal with that behaviour?

Comment: @CameronNemo I am willing to deal with that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the suspend/shutdown options in the cog wheel at the top right there is another option I consider quicker and less error prone that does not require a mouse.

On notebooks and desktops there is a "off" button. Here is an example for a random notebook (on mine it is on the left side):

[image]

Pressing it will show a popup with several options. By default it is lock, suspend, restart and shutdown. It looks like this:

[image]

([source](http://simionbaws.ro/linux/ubuntu-14-04-ctrlaltdel-shutdown-dialog/))

So the easiest way to me to shutdown a machine:

- Hit the off button
- Hit arrow left
- Hit enter

Answer (score 1):

Workaround, create a .desktop file for shutdown:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Shutdown
Exec=bash -c "dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop"
Icon=???
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Or use Xubuntu ;) there are confirmation dialogs for all this actions.

There is also an bugreport for this "problem" on Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/783808